# Organization Chart - Allow editing by multiple team members using C#

Tags: c#, xml, charts, tree, organization

I am working on creating an org chart for my organization and I am using C# as the technology to implement the same with XML to store the data.  I have few challenges and need your guidance:

1. If an employee has more than one manager/supervisor, how to establish the relationship?
2. How to handle a case wherein one of the employee of an already existing chart (tree) wants to create a chart from his level, but he is already in a tree created by his manager/supervisor?

Comment: Put the data in to a database where multiple people can edit data at same time. Use SQL Server (not excel or access which does not allow shared access).  An xml file in windows cannot be shared while a database does allow multiple users do edit simultaneously.  Then create the xml file from the database.  A chart is an output of the database and depending on the tool used to display the chart will allow lines to cross.  If you may not be able to print on one sheet all situations.

Comment: Thanks jdweng.  But you have not answered to my queries.  It is not about editing the chart at the same time.  Lets assume, A has two subordinates B and C, B has one subordinate D, and C has three subordinate E, F and G.  When B logs-in and tries to create a chart starting from his level, then what will happen to the chart already created by A?

Comment: What happens if the opposite occurs if B enter his chart and is manager isn't in the chart?Or somebody quits and there is employees with no manager.Your code has to be robust to handle all cases.You need to create a database with the organization and then simply output the database to an xml file. Printing the chart is the same.  The print algorithm has to be able to enumerate through the database and output all the data.  Usually an organization database has an employee and manager in two columns.  So you recursively go through org from root to leaf.  In some cases you may have hanging nodes.